# Checking multiple roles of a user within a club system

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am member over complicating my member ship table.
I have obv created my application using asp.net idneity within it I have my main roles declared which has the following.

[image]

Then I have what is called my club members in the following table.

[image]

Which as you see will map the user to the club

[image]

[image]

My Question is in link how can I ensure that using ef core how does one insure that the user is either a clubmod, admin , or super admin to allow them to create clubs?.

Obv I can use the below for one role but how do i check that he is master role admin level its not just enough i check he is club admin but also site admin if you get me.

```
User.IsInRole("ClubMod");
```

Comment: Just OR them together? `if (User.IsInRole("ClubMod") || User.IsInRole("Admin") ...)`?

Comment: But I also need to check if they belong to clubs

Comment: @rogue39nin Please, edit your post to clarify your question.